# Maximum integer value find in list<int>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<int>` with several elements.  I know I can get all the values if I iterate through it with `foreach`, but I just want the maximum int value in the list.

```
var l = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 2 };
```

Answer (score 83):

Assuming .NET Framework 3.5 or greater:

```
var l = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 2 };
var max = l.Max();
Console.WriteLine(max); // prints 3
```

Lots and lots of cool time-savers like these in the [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) class.

Answer (score 13):

Use Enumerable.Max

```
int max = l.Max();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int max = (from l in list select l).Max().FirstOrDefault();
```

as per comment this should be

```
l.Max();
```

Comment: Unless `l` is a list of Enumerables this won't compile, also there is no point in `(from l in list select l)`

Comment: @Yuriy your right - I am currently doing lots of Linq to EF and was forgetting that this was a simple l.Max(); I also made the assumption that List<int> which is declared in the title of this post is IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Use this Syntax:

```
l.OrderByDescending(x => x).First(); //for maximum

l.OrderBy(x => x).First(); // for minimum
```

or You can use Max() and Min() Methods from linq.

I hope what I said will be useful to you... .

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

int Max = list.Max();
```

Comment: This does answer the question! But I think [Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295125/712526) already has that covered.

Comment: @jpaugh It answers the question, but it duplicates two of previous answers.

Comment: I have used int Max = list.Max(); but in my case namespace  using System.Linq;  was missed therefore Max() not applied with list.

Comment: while using IDE, it's obvious that using System.Linq is missing, but for online editors like on hackerrank etc, it's a important hint

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = listOfInts[0];
for(int i = 1; i < listOfInts.Count; i++) {
    max = Math.Max(max, listOfInts[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Linq:

```
l.Sort();
int min = l[0]; //1
int max = l[l.Count - 1]; //3
```