# How to get the maximum Value in a generic TList<Integer>?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

What is the easiest way to get the maximum value in a `TList<Integer>`?

```
function GetMaximum(AList: TList<Integer>): Integer;
begin
  Assert(AList.Count > 0);
  Result := ?;
end;
```

I read that C# has a `AList.Max`, is there something like that in Delphi?

Comment: The .NET way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295112/maximum-integer-value-find-in-listint

Comment: Of course, .net has lovely extension methods to do this sort of thing.......

Comment: The [Spring Framework for Delphi](http://www.spring4d.org) defines IEnumerable<T> interface which provides LINQ-like enumerable extension methods. Recommended!

Comment: @Erwin Isn't IEnumerable<T> defined in system.generics.collections as well? What is that the Spring Framework adds to that?

Comment: @Marjan Venema: In Generics.Collections the *class* TEnumerable<T> is defined. On the other hand in the Spring Framework for Delphi the collections are *interface* based. In unit Spring.Collections.Lists a class TList<T> is defined which provides the extension methods, and ultimately implements IEnumerable(T). You can call List.Max, but also List.Reversed for example. See also [Demo.Spring.Enumerators project](http://delphi-spring-framework.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v1.0_beta1/Samples/SpringDemos/Demo.Collections/).

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Also Nick Hodges has written nice series of [articles](http://www.nickhodges.com/page/Dependency-Injection-Series.aspx) on Dependency Injection with [Delphi Spring Framework](http://www.spring4d.org/). You also have [Lazy initialization](http://www.spring4d.org/spring4d-in-action/lazy-initialization/) and [Nullable Types](http://www.spring4d.org/spring4d-in-action/nullable-types/). Like I said: recommended!

Comment: @Erwin These aren't extension methods though, are they?

Comment: The (unfortunately no longer maintained) Generic Delphi Collections from Alex Ciobanu supports a lot of LINQ like extension methods, including a generic Max function: http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/wiki/EnexOperations

Comment: @David Heffernan: in unit [Spring.Collections.pas](http://delphi-spring-framework.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v1.0_beta1/Source/Base/Collections/Spring.Collections.pas) the interface IEnumerable<T> is defined. The comments there says: 'Provides limited LINQ-like enumerable extension methods'. I think you can call them kind of extension methods, don't you think so?

Comment: @Erwin I wouldn't call them extension methods. Delphi lacks support for those. But that doesn't mean I don't think spring4d is cool!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a fun example with a `MaxValue` implementation on a generic container:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Defaults, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyList<T> = class(TList<T>)
  public
    function MaxValue: T;
  end;

{ TMyList<T> }

function TMyList<T>.MaxValue: T;
var
  i: Integer;
  Comparer: IComparer<T>;
begin
  if Count=0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Cannot call TMyList<T>.MaxValue on an empty list');
  Comparer := TComparer<T>.Default;
  Result := Self[0];
  for i := 1 to Count-1 do
    if Comparer.Compare(Self[i], Result)>0 then
      Result := Self[i];
end;

var
  IntList: TMyList<Integer>;
  DoubleList: TMyList<Double>;
  StringList: TMyList<string>;

begin
  IntList := TMyList<Integer>.Create;
  IntList.AddRange([10, 5, 12, -49]);
  Writeln(IntList.MaxValue);

  DoubleList := TMyList<Double>.Create;
  DoubleList.AddRange([10.0, 5.0, 12.0, -49.0]);
  Writeln(DoubleList.MaxValue);

  StringList := TMyList<string>.Create;
  StringList.AddRange(['David Heffernan', 'Uwe Raabe', 'Warren P', 'Jens Mühlenhoff']);
  Writeln(StringList.MaxValue);

  Readln;
end.
```

Because we cannot come up with a generic equivalent to `low(Integer)` I raise an exception when the method is called on an empty list.

The output is:

```
12
 1.20000000000000E+0001
Warren P
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's an alternative answer:  Use the `Spring.Collections.pas` unit from the Spring4D framework:  (found here:  http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/)

```
program ListEnumerableDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses 
    System.SysUtils 
  , Spring.Collections;

var 
  List: IList<Integer>; 
  Enumerable: IEnumerable<Integer>;

begin 
  try 
    List := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>; 
    List.AddRange([1,6,2,9,54,3,2,7,9,1]);

    Enumerable := List; 
    WriteLn(Enumerable.Max); 
    ReadLn; 
  except 
    on E: Exception do 
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message); 
  end; 
end.
```

Comment: +1, for using `ENumerable<T>` as it is not a `TList<T>` problem at all.

Comment: Since IList<T> inherits from IEnumerable<T>, we can use List.Max without casting it to IEnumerable<T> :)

Comment: @Jeroen I don't understand that comment at all. The answer uses a generic list. Just not the variant from Generics.Collections.

Comment: In Spring, many more than just `IList` exposes `IEnumerable<T>`. That's the crux of Nick's answer.

Comment: @Nick How does `IEnumerable<Integer>.Max` handle an empty container?

Comment: @David: Good question. I tried the above demo and commented out the AddRange which populates the list. It does what I hoped it would do. Raises exception  EInvalidOpException with message 'This sequence is empty.'

Answer (score 3):

Using `for .. in`:

```
function GetMaximum(AList: TList<Integer>): Integer;
var
  I: Integer
begin
  Assert(AList.Count > 0);
  Result := Low(Integer);
  for I in AList do
    if I > Result then
      Result := I;
end;
```

Comment: Can this be done in a way that is equivalently powerful to having `IEnumerable` in .net? In other words, could you make a Generic implementation for GetMaximum, using generics/traits?

Comment: @Warren -- the Spring.Collections.pas unit has IEnumerable<T> which would make this a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using the Spring collections is probably the easiest way. However there may be reasons to not use them (already using Generics.Collections all over the place).

So here is how to make a new type that extends `TEnumerable<T>` with a `function Max: T`.

```
type
  Enumerable<T> = record
  private
    source: TEnumerable<T>;
  public
    function Max: T;

    class operator Implicit(const value: TEnumerable<T>): Enumerable<T>;
  end;

class operator Enumerable<T>.Implicit(
  const value: TEnumerable<T>): Enumerable<T>;
begin
  Result.source := value;
end;

function Enumerable<T>.Max: T;
var
  default: IComparer<T>;
  x, y: T;
  flag: Boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(source) then
    raise EArgumentNilException.Create('Source');
  default := TComparer<T>.Default;

  flag := False;
  for x in source do
  begin
    if flag then
    begin
      if default.Compare(x, y) > 0 then
        y := x;
    end
    else
    begin
      y := x;
      flag := True;
    end;
  end;
  if flag then
    Result := y
  else
    raise EListError.Create('source is empty');
end;
```

The code is basically a port of the .Net `Enumerable.Max<T>` extension method from `System.Linq`. You can use it just like in Nicks example.

The interesting thing for those interested in their binary size: linker is able to remove the methods that are never used.